# Get data using Mantle

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am working on an application and I am blocked when I try to read values from the data received from a server.

I have this code:

```
//Item.h
@interface Item : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *itemId;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end

//Item.m
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
             @"itemId" : @"id",
             @"name" : @"name"
             };
}
```

Here is the code I think is wrong:

```
// responseObject is the data received from server using AFNetworking
for (NSDictionary *dict in responseObject) {
    Item *myItem = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:Item.class fromJSONDictionary:dict error:nil];
}
```

And the schema of responseObject is:

```
{
  "message": "message",
  "success": true,
  "item": {
    "id": 14576,
    "name": "name",
    "created_at": 1438245872,
    "repeat": false,
    "thumb": {
      "src": "urlToImage",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 120
    }
  }
}
```

And when I run the application, the crash message is

```
-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa737365636375737
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa737365636375737'
```

I also have tried using the following sentence to get the data but in this case itemId and name are nil:

```
Item *myItem = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:Item.class fromJSONDictionary:responseObject error:nil];
```

So I have 2 questions: how can I make this work? And, how should I get the same for the values of "thumb"? I see it is a nested block and I think this could be even more problematic.

I hope you can help me to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the object from responseObject as dictionary?

Comment: @ReinierMelian do you mean the used in the for instruction? It shows the key of each one: message, success, item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare full key path related to JSON data:

```c
//Item.m
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
             @"itemId" : @"item.id",
             @"name" : @"item.name"
            };
}
```

To parse **thumb** you could use key path `"item.thumb.src"`. But better create separate class like this:

```c
//Thumb.h
@interface Thumb : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSURL *src;
@end

//Thumb.m
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
   return @{
            @"src" : @"src"
          };
}
```

and then use `Item`with next changes:

```c
//Item.h
@interface Item : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *itemId;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonatomic) Thumb *thumb;
@end

//Item.m
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
             @"itemId" : @"item.id",
             @"name" : @"item.name"
             @"Thumb" : @"item.thumb"
           };
}
```

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I read in another post (I cannot find now the link) where it is explained that accessing to the values using dots like "item.id" does not work. But even if it works I need to solve first the other question and then apply your suggestion

Comment: There are good examples on the [Mantle's] (https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) github page. Into the `@implementation GHIssue` next code has used dots: `... @"reporterLogin": @"user.login", ...`. So I think it is a normal to use dots.